# Find equal columns between two dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two `pandas` data frames, `a` and `b`:

```
a1   a2   a3   a4   a5   a6   a7
1    3    4    5    3    4    5
0    2    0    3    0    2    1
2    5    6    5    2    1    2
```

and

```
b1   b2   b3   b4   b5   b6   b7
3    5    4    5    1    4    3
0    1    2    3    0    0    2
2    2    1    5    2    6    5
```

The two data frames contain exactly the same data, but in a different order and with different column names. Based on the numbers in the two data frames, I would like to be able to match each column name in `a` to each column name in `b`.

It is not as easy as simply comparing the first row of `a` with the first row of `b` as there are duplicated values, for example both `a4` and `a7` have the value `5` so it is not possible to immediately match them to either `b2` or `b4`.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's one way leveraging [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to check for equality between both dataframes and taking [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) on the result to check where all rows match. Then we can obtain indexing arrays for both dataframe's column names from the result of [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)  (with @piR's contribution):

```
i, j = np.where((a.values[:,None] == b.values[:,:,None]).all(axis=0))
dict(zip(a.columns[j], b.columns[i]))
# {'a7': 'b2', 'a6': 'b3', 'a4': 'b4', 'a2': 'b7'}
```

Comment: I stuck my nose in your post.  Hopefully, you don't mind.  Please change it to your liking.

Comment: Ah on the contrary :) Nice approach, and checking on large dataframes it slightly improves performance @piRSquared

Answer (score 16):

Here is a way using `sort_values`:

```
m=df1.T.sort_values(by=[*df1.index]).index
n=df2.T.sort_values(by=[*df2.index]).index
d=dict(zip(m,n))
print(d)
```

---

```
{'a1': 'b5', 'a5': 'b1', 'a2': 'b7', 'a3': 'b6', 'a6': 'b3', 'a7': 'b2', 'a4': 'b4'}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing nice command Anky, could you please explain more on `[*df1.index]` part please? Will be grateful to you, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Sure, `sort_values(by=..)` takes a list as a parameter so I am unpacking the index to a list here , you could also do `list(df1.index)` instead of `[*df1.index]` :)

Answer (score 12):

One way of `merge`

```
s=df1.T.reset_index().merge(df2.T.assign(match=lambda x : x.index))
dict(zip(s['index'],s['match']))
{'a1': 'b5', 'a2': 'b7', 'a3': 'b6', 'a4': 'b4', 'a5': 'b1', 'a6': 'b3', 'a7': 'b2'}
```

Comment: I thought I'd add another clever solution only to see that it was the same as yours (-:  whoops.

Answer (score 8):

#### dictionary comprehensions

Use a `tuple` of the column values as the hashable key in a dictionary

```
d = {(*t,): c for c, t in df2.items()}
{c: d[(*t,)] for c, t in df1.items()}

{'a1': 'b5',
 'a2': 'b7',
 'a3': 'b6',
 'a4': 'b4',
 'a5': 'b1',
 'a6': 'b3',
 'a7': 'b2'}
```

Just in case we don't have perfect representation, I've only produced the dictionary for columns where there is a match.

```
d2 = {(*t,): c for c, t in df2.items()}
d1 = {(*t,): c for c, t in df1.items()}

{d1[c]: d2[c] for c in {*d1} & {*d2}}

{'a5': 'b1',
 'a2': 'b7',
 'a7': 'b2',
 'a6': 'b3',
 'a3': 'b6',
 'a1': 'b5',
 'a4': 'b4'}
```

---

#### `idxmax`

This borders on the absurd...  Don't actually do this.

```
{c: df2.T.eq(df1[c]).sum(1).idxmax() for c in df1}

{'a1': 'b5',
 'a2': 'b7',
 'a3': 'b6',
 'a4': 'b4',
 'a5': 'b1',
 'a6': 'b3',
 'a7': 'b2'}
```

Comment: How is it that, I can understand each expression in these statements, yet not fully see in my head what is really going here?  Kinda like chess, I know how to move all the piece on the board, but can't see more that 2 move ahead.

Comment: Okay... I have digested this now and it is absolutely simply yet, brilliant. +1