# How to compare two differently ordered Pandas Dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have two differently ordered dataframes that I want to check for equality. Order does not matter as long as the contents match up. These below would be equal.

```
    val1  val2
0    1     2
1    2     1

    val1  val2
0    2     1
1    1     2
```

I am thinking to first check for size, then loop through df1, check if the row at 'i' can be found in df2, then remove both rows and continue through until it executes successfully or fails to find a row. Is there a way to do it without looping though?

Comment: looks [similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59721120/find-equal-columns-between-two-dataframes/59721161#59721161)

Comment: equality as columns or rows ?

Comment: @Datanovice I want to check if the contents in rows match up exactly. Columns are assumed to be same format

Comment: can you  post the expected output?

Comment: I didn't really have an expected output in mind, just wanted to check for set equality where a set of (2,1,3) would equal (1,2,3).

Comment: Similar to the post @anky points to, we can do smth like `(df1.values[:,None] == df2.values).all(-1).any(0)`

Comment: I'd say so yes, since it is very similar, and several answers are possible fairly easy to adapt :) @anky

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain what is happening in the code @yatu?

Comment: A little long to explain tbh. To do with broadcasting. Perhaps break out the answer in parts, and check out the relevant docs.  This one will help https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the number of occurrences per item must match exactly. So (A,B,C,C) != (A,B,B,C). I will have to see if there's a way to remove each row after finding its match